# Reference folder in solution explorer not showing? (VS2010)

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Hello I'm looking at a colleagues web application that is written in C# and the app have a com file in it. Unfortunately I can't find the reference folder. I tried adding it again and displaying ALL files/folders and still nothing.

The only folder that appears when I add a new com is a bin folder but it doesn't show anything else beside the com file.

I find the reference folder pretty useful so if anyone have any idea on how to make it appear. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It must be ASP.NET WEb Site rather than Web Application. There is no reference folder for projects of type `Web Site`. You can go to project properties and add references there.

Decide when to use which:

http://vishaljoshi.blogspot.com/2009/08/web-application-project-vs-web-site.html

Comment: Ok thanks for the info! I found a work around by using object browser to see all the components of the file.

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to have a VB.NET web application then there is no references folder either. Double-click "My Project" or go to the project properties and find the Reference tab.